# Hybrid App security encryption

Tags: security, mobile, encryption

So I am toying around with an idea to add some functionality to my app and that would be the ability for users to send a PM to another user, my question is how best to secure this.

I was thinking of doing something like this

- Users have to validate themselves in app ( basically a password to identify themselves )
- The system pings the server with their ID and pin ( password ) send via https
- The response will be an encrypted JSON object with any messages they have etc
- Once back in the app, decrypt and store it in indexDB
- Any responses back to server will be encrypted again and sent over https and decrypted and stored once on the server

Obviously this doesn't help if the person looses their phone etc but I'm trying to get some feedback on the approach and if it seem secure enough, as anyone with malicious intentions would have to go through multiple steps to try and circumvent the system and would also need to have a users ID and password.

Comment: Who are you defending against?  HTTPS already provides encryption and protection against a man-in-the-middle attack (by validating the server's certificate).  You haven't made it clear why you are encrypting on top of an already-encrypted connection.

Comment: Hi indiv, Well basically I wanted to add the extra layer between so , if a person were to see the requesting string they could not just place that service string in the browser and get the JSON extract as it could contain email addresses etc. I figured if I encrypted that information as well it would be utterly useless to a person if they somehow got the api keys but more so when I add a messaging service to the app, I don't want that information to possibly be circumvented because that should be personal between the two people